# how to combine 2 different array lists [Angular,typescript]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 arraylist as below where I have to combine the array to get all the values in the new array list where the uuid will be common in both of the lists , the final list should have all the values associated witht he UUID in the both arraylist

list 1:

```
[
  {
  "uuid":"01",
  "plan" : "aaaa",
  "other_details":"xxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "02",
    "plan" : "bbbb",
    "other_details":"yyyyyyy"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "03",
    "plan" : "cccc",
    "other_details":"zzzzzz"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "04",
    "plan" : "dddd",
    "other_details":"uuuuuu"
  }
]
```

list 2:

```
[
  {
  "uuid":"01",
  "office" : "India",
  "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "02",
    "office" : "USA",
    "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "03",
    "office" : "Germany",
    "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "04",
    "office" : "Australia",
    "status":"shutdown"
  }
]
```

I have to combine 2 array lists with unique "UUID",
the array should look like

```
[
  {
  "uuid":"01",
  "plan" : "aaaa",
  "other_details":"xxxxxx",
    "office" : "India",
  "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "02",
    "plan" : "bbbb",
    "other_details":"yyyyyyy",
    "office" : "USA",
    "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "03",
    "plan" : "cccc",
    "other_details":"zzzzzz",
    "office" : "Germany",
    "status":"running"
  },
  {
    "uuid" : "04",
    "plan" : "dddd",
    "other_details":"uuuuuu",
    "office" : "Australia",
    "status":"shutdown"
  }
]
```

can I iterate the array as below ?

```
   for(listItem1 in arraylist1){  //assuming I am storing the arraylist in variable arraylist1
     for (listitem2 in arraylist2){
    if(listItem1.uuid=== listItem2.uuid){
listItem = "" //assign values
}
    }
    }
```

how to create the 3rd array list and store the items in the arraylist

Comment: How about `listItem = { ...listItem1, ...listItem2 }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this; used spread operator of ECMAScript to simplify it.

```
const mergedList = listOne.map(listItem1 => ({...listItem1, ...listTwo.find(listItem2 => listItem2.id === listItem1.id)}))
```